# Notarizing Mac App in bamboo with install4j9

Tags: macos, bamboo, install4j, osx-gatekeeper

I have recently updated from install4j6 -> install4j9, which I use within in my build server in bamboo. Bamboo has no issues code signing the files but the notarization process in never ran. I have no issues doing this manually on my Mac, but within bamboo it never runs. I've seen some posts about xcode plugins for bamboo, but I am not sure whether I need to implement script tasks to perform the notarization manually, or if install4j9 supports this. Any help/resources would be appreciated.

Here are the logs I am seeing from bamboo on my end:

```
[INFO] Important: macOS media sets have to be notarized before distribution.
[INFO]   More information in the code signing help.
```

Answer (score 1):

install4j can only perform notarization if the build runs on macOS. Notarization involves calling command line utilities on macOS that perform operations that my not be reverse engineered on other platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the response, as this is what I feared... I am trying to add this notarization process as part of my build process within bamboo.  I have done some research and found some resources about a technology called Darling, which would allow me to use xcode tools on my linux server.  I am trying to see what the best way to go about doing this would be.

Comment: Yes, maybe you can do that, although IIRC Apple forbids running Xcode binaries on non-Apple hardware. FWIW, we will add notarization via Github actions in install4j 10 later this year.

Comment: That's great to hear about install4j10.  Do you have any recommendations as far as a potential fix for the notarization process in a build server? Of course I can just manually do one on my mac but that could become tedious on a release by release basis.

Comment: The only way now is to use a macOS build server

Answer (score 0):

If notarization might be executed at MacOS only then you can start Remote agent at your Mac env and configure Bamboo Server to send this job to that agent. Then it doesn't matter what OS Bamboo Server is running.